# How to convert .osm file into .xml

Tags: openstreetmap, convert, xml

I downloaded a file `.osm`. I want to have the same file but with extension `.xml`
To do that, I downloaded `osmconverter` but the problem is, as states in wikipedia I can convert the `.osm` file into specific formates and `.xml` is not one of them.

Please let me know how to do that because I need to do further processing on the file and it must be `.xml`

Answer (score 2):

The [*.osm file is a *.xml file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML). There is no need to convert it. Open the file within an editor of your choice and you will see the xml structure. If your application needs a file with *.xml ending simply rename it or use the *.osm file as an input. Both should be fine.

Comment: ok..but i downloaded this file from geophabrik bremen-regbez-latest.osm and i cant open it

Comment: Did you unzip the osm.bz2 file? After unzipping you should be able to open it. Which tool are you using?

Comment: I wonder where you downloaded that from. http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/bremen.html offers .osm.pbf and .osm.bz2.  While the first is a compressed pbf format, the second is a zipped version of the original XML format. It is 24 MB large, so maybe too large for a text editor. There is no subregion defined for Bremen.

Comment: @zehpunktbarron i unzipped the .bz2 file using 7z and it gives me one file of type .osm and i tried to open the .osm file with my editor to rename it to bremen.xml but the editior say it is too big

Comment: If you just want to rename the file you don't need to open it. I just recommended you to open it so you could see the structure of the file. right-clicking on the file and renaming it should be fine. However, depending on your application *.osm **is a** *.xml file which normaly doesn't have to be renamed.